# Завершение работы функции C++

Tags: c++

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно завершить функцию в C++ по истечению некоторого времени. Дело в том, что при ее вызове собираются некоторые данные в видимо бесконечном цикле. Каким образом ее можно завершить после определенного времени если при этом доступа к коду этой функции нет?

Comment: Не совсем полно Вы описали ситуацию, но как вариант могу предложить запускать функцию в отдельном треде и потом этот тред уничтожать.

Comment: Кроме `alarm()`, `signal()` и `sigsetjmp()/siglongjmp()` ничего в голову не приходит.

Учтите, решение (не зная, что делает функция) абсолютно **не безопасно...**

Правда, это все для \*nix.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться завершить функцию. Наоборот, это функция должна сотрудничать: интересоваться, не нужно ли ей завершиться раньше времени, и завершаться сама, если нужно. Только так, и никак иначе.

Comment: @avknsk, нужно больше подробностей. Что за функция? Почему нет доступа к коду?

Comment: @avknst, а главное - **какая ОС?**.

Средствами именно *языка С++* данная задача не решается.

Comment: Если функция не делает то, что вам надо — просто не пользуйтесь ей. Если нет варианта не пользоваться (например, функция — часть ненастраиваемого фреймворка), тогда не повезло, задача не решается.

Comment: @VladD, крутой фреймворк наверное. Собирает данные в бесконечном цикле и никому не отдает.

Comment: @dzhioev: (шёпотом) _я сам тоже не верю, что нельзя просто не пользоваться функцией_

Comment: А кто мешает запустить в отдельном треде? Правда треды просто так лучше не убивать. В этом случае делают отдельный процесс.

Comment: @KoVadim, треды ему уже предлагали, а вот процесс - это новое. 

Только производительность совсем (по сравнению с тредом) просядет. Зато безопасно.

Comment: Если он у него функция очень долго исполняется (например, несколько часов), то накладные расходы на процесс будут минимальные.